# Auto create default records on creation of new client record

Tags: django, django-models

When a new client record is created, I would like to automatically create (client related) default records across various models. For example, after creating a new client I would like to set up default billing parameters for the client in related tables.

I understand how to set defaults in a model; however, I am not clear on the best approach to catch the new record creation and trigger the creation of related records.

Comment: `post_save` signal can be used for this.

Answer (score 0):

`post_save` signal is your solution.

**Docs:**
[How to connect signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders)
[post_save signal description](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save)